# Create a zip file inside dropbox

Tags: dropbox-api

I have a system in dropbox where i have folders for multiple users with contents inside that i have them download every now and then. Anyways, I want to zip the contents of each persons folder for faster downloading as downloading folders over dropbox is very slow (at least to my knowledge unless there is a faster way to download besides sharing url) How could I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately the Dropbox API doesn't currently offer a way to create/download a zip of a folder, or otherwise download folders in bulk, but we'll consider it a feature request.

---

Edit:
The Dropbox API now offers the ability to download folders as zips:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download_zip

If you're using an official SDK, there will also be a corresponding method for this endpoint.